# SQL SELECT WHERE Trouble any ideas helpful

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, where-clause

I have two tables parent and child (related as such on PK/FK GUID)

Child has a Timestamp (the record creation date/time).

What I want to do is get only the most recent child record AND the parent record, FOR EACH parent record.

```
SELECT 
    dbo_Parents.ParentName, 
    dbo_ChildEntry.CountPropertys, 
    dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp
FROM 
    dbo_Parents INNER JOIN dbo_ChildEntry 
ON
    dbo_Parents.ParentID = dbo_ChildEntry.ParentID
WHERE 
    ([WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?]))
```

Comment: You have to define "most recent".

Comment: I would like to select only the child row with the most recent datetimestamp (ie which ever record contains the timestamp closest to Now())

Comment: Do you expect one result row per parent, or one result in total?

Comment: I did a poor job of saying this initially, I want one result (most recent child + parent) per parent row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you want the most recent entry, you have to use TOP 1 and order by.

```
SELECT TOP 1
dbo_Parents.ParentName, 
dbo_ChildEntry.CountPropertys, 
dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp 
FROM dbo_Parents 
INNER JOIN dbo_ChildEntry ON dbo_Parents.ParentID = dbo_ChildEntry.ParentID 
ORDER BY dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp desc
```

Edit after clarification: "the most recent child record AND the parent record, FOR EACH parent record":

```
WHERE dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp = 
      ( Select Max( dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp )
               from dbo_ChildEntry 
               where dbo_Parents.ParentID = dbo_ChildEntry.ParentId )
```

Comment: My bad -- I want should have been more clear (question edited). I want to return the most recent child and its parent FOR EACH parent.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE dbo.ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp = ( Select Max( c.DateTimeStamp )
                                         from dbo.ChildEntry c
                                        where dbo_Parents.ParentID = c.ParentId )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.ParentName, 
    c.CountPropertys, 
    c.DateTimeStamp
from (
    select max(DateTimeStamp) as DateTimeStamp, ParentID
    from dbo_ChildEntry
    group by ParentID) cm
inner join dbo_ChildEntry c on cm.DateTimeStamp = c.DateTimeStamp and cm.ParentID = c.ParentID
inner join dbo_Parents p on c.ParentID = p.ParentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you clarified you'd like one row per parent, try this.  For every row, it searches for a child row that has a later timestamp.  In the WHERE clause, it filters on rows that do not have a "next" child.

```
SELECT 
    dbo_Parents.ParentName, 
    cur.CountPropertys, 
    cur.DateTimeStamp
FROM dbo_Parents 
INNER JOIN dbo_ChildEntry cur
    ON dbo_Parents.ParentID = cur.ParentID
LEFT JOIN dbo_ChildEntry next
    ON dbo_Parents.ParentID = next.ParentID
    AND next.DateTimeStamp > cur.DateTimeStamp
WHERE
    next.DateTimeStamp is null
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT     dbo_Parents.ParentName,     dbo_ChildEntry.CountPropertys,     
max(dbo_ChildEntry.DateTimeStamp)
FROM     dbo_Parents 
INNER JOIN dbo_ChildEntry ON    dbo_Parents.ParentID = dbo_ChildEntry.ParentID
group by dbo_Parents.ParentName,     dbo_ChildEntry.CountPropertys
```

Comment: -1 You're grouping on dbo_ChildEntry.CountPropertys, so max(datetimestamp) only finds the maximum timestamp for children with the same CountPropertyes.